# Using Regex in C# to check for optional comma seperated repeating sequence

Tags: c#, regex

Thanks in advance to all help on this.

I am rather new to regex and I am finding it a little difficult to master.

I have a `WindowsForm C#` in which the user can enter a set of data in a comma separated format as a single string. The data is also grouped using brackets ().

Each group consists of

`(int type, int year, int age_start, int age_end)`

In the text box the user can enter multiple groups

`(group1),(group2)`

I have managed to get the regex for splitting the groups

`Regex RejectStringRegex = new Regex(@"\(([^)]*)\)");`

and to split the data in the groups (I just have realised this might not account for spaces in the text)

`Regex SubRejectStringRegex = new Regex(@"(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+)");`

What I can't get right is how to reject malformed group strings for example

`(1,89,10,10),(`

or

`(1,14,10,10),(2,15,20,30),(10`

The code to perform the check currently looks like this. Note that I separated the `regex` checks as I am using them to process the data later into a `List<>` however if it is simpler to do it as one process then I am fine with this as well.

```
private bool CheckForValidReject()
{
    bool StringValid = false;
    Regex RejectStringRegex = new Regex(@"\(([^)]*)\)");
    Regex SubRejectStringRegex = new Regex(@"(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+)");

    MatchCollection AllMatches = RejectStringRegex.Matches(tbRejectString.Text);

    if (AllMatches.Count > 0)
    {
        StringValid = true;
        foreach (Match SomeMatch in AllMatches)
        {
            Match RejectMatch = SubRejectStringRegex.Match(SomeMatch.Groups[0].Value);

            if (!RejectMatch.Success)
            {
                StringValid = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return StringValid;
}
```

N.B: the text box is checked for empty string before calling.

Comment: If you always have 4 parenthesized comma separated numbers, you can try `@"^\s*(?<type>\d+)\s*,\s*(?<year>\d+)\s*,\s*(?<agestart>\d+)\s*,\s*(?<ageend>\d+)\s*$"`.

Comment: You can count the number of `(` and `)` : `tbRejectString.Text.Count(f => f == '(') == tbRejectString.Text.Count(f => f == ')')`

Comment: Do you accept group within a group ?

Comment: @Thomas - no each group is individual.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - thanks I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the `()`: try [`^\(\s*(?<type>\d+)\s*,\s*(?<year>\d+)\s*,\s*(?<agestart>\d+)\s*,(?<ageend>\d+)\s*\)\s*$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5c(%5cs*(%3f%3ctype%3e%5cd%2b)%5cs*%2c%5cs*(%3f%3cyear%3e%5cd%2b)%5cs*%2c%5cs*(%3f%3cagestart%3e%5cd%2b)%5cs*%2c(%3f%3cageend%3e%5cd%2b)%5cs*%5c)%5cs*%24&i=(1%2c89%2c10%2c10)&o=m).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Off-Topic: How do you added the link to regexstorm to that comment? I tried to use the permalink that contains parenthesis. This won't work with Stackoverflow. But I tested it only at answers not on comments.

Comment: @Verarind: to make a link in comments, you need to put `[` then the text, then `]`, then `(` (right after the closing square bracket), then URL, and then a `)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes I know but the link contains a closing parenthesis and that causes the "comment parser" to cut the whole link at this position.

Comment: @Verarind: Sometimes, it does not work and I do not know why :(

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the two options you gave above only works on one group. If the entry is `(1,14,10,10),(2,13,11,12)` there is no match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
^\(\s*(?<type>\d+)\s*,\s*(?<year>\d+)\s*,\s*(?<agestart>\d+)\s*,(?<ageend>\d+)\s*\)\s*(,\s*\(\s*(?<type>\d+)\s*,\s*(?<year>\d+)\s*,\s*(?<agestart>\d+)\s*,(?<ageend>\d+)\s*\)\s*)*$
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5C(%5Cs*(%3F%3Ctype%3E%5Cd%2B)%5Cs*%2C%5Cs*(%3F%3Cyear%3E%5Cd%2B)%5Cs*%2C%5Cs*(%3F%3Cagestart%3E%5Cd%2B)%5Cs*%2C(%3F%3Cageend%3E%5Cd%2B)%5Cs*%5C)%5Cs*(%2C%5Cs*%5C(%5Cs*(%3F%3Ctype%3E%5Cd%2B)%5Cs*%2C%5Cs*(%3F%3Cyear%3E%5Cd%2B)%5Cs*%2C%5Cs*(%3F%3Cagestart%3E%5Cd%2B)%5Cs*%2C(%3F%3Cageend%3E%5Cd%2B)%5Cs*%5C)%5Cs*)*%5Cr%3F%24&i=(1%2C89%2C10%2C10)%0D%0A(1%2C14%2C10%2C10)%2C(2%2C13%2C11%2C12)&o=nm), use with `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` flag.

[image]

In C#, you need to get the groups and then access all values via `Captures` CaptureCollection.

Here is a demo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

// And then...

var strs = new List<string> { "(1,89,10,10)", "(1,14,10,10),(2,13,11,12)"};
var pattern = @"^\(\s*(?<type>\d+)\s*,\s*(?<year>\d+)\s*,\s*(?<agestart>\d+)\s*,(?<ageend>\d+)\s*\)\s*(,\s*\(\s*(?<type>\d+)\s*,\s*(?<year>\d+)\s*,\s*(?<agestart>\d+)\s*,(?<ageend>\d+)\s*\)\s*)*$";
foreach (var s in strs)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(s, pattern, RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);  
    if (match.Success) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", and ", match.Groups["type"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList()));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", and ", match.Groups["year"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList()));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", and ", match.Groups["agestart"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList()));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", and ", match.Groups["ageend"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList()));
    }
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/10XXkQ)